# Path stroke has holes in paperjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I am using paper.js to draw paths along the mouse coordinates. Unfortunatelly the path stroke is having "holes" when the angel of a corner is very small (see picture).

[paperjs path with holes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHGH3.png)

Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

Thanks
Robert

Comment: Did you check the behavior with different [strokeCaps](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#strokecap)?

Comment: I already tried all 3 possible strokeCap values but none of them solved my problem :-(

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comment, using a `round` stroke cap should mitigate this issue.
That said, this kind of drawing artifact is inherent to the way the Canvas API draws strokes. And Paper.js relies on it to draw its shapes.
This remind me of this [issue](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1560) which was very similar to yours.

I think that the best workaround to avoid this could be to somehow simplify the path so that this very shard angle between close points never happens. Paper.js can help you achieving this (tool min distance, path.smooth(), ...).

Comment: Unfortunatelly, path.strokeCap = "round" didn't solve the problem :-(